# strategy.order.alert_message different lines

Tags: tradingview-api, alerts

For an API i need an alert message, so I would use the {{strategy.order.alert_message}} command in my alert. This would then refer to my Pinescript code. There is one problem though, I want this alert message to be in different lines, but I don't seem to find this in Pinescript. Lets say I want following text in my alert, so all on different lines. How would I be able to put this in my pinescript code after the ''alert_message'' command? Because when I paste it in my pinescript code it sees each line as a different pinescript line (which is wrong)

{
"bot_id": "3114",
"action": "open-position",
"base_asset": " ",
"quote_asset": " ",
"api_key": " "
}

I hope u understand my question/problem.[How i want my command to look like, but by using pinescript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixc9q.png)[How it would look like in Pinescript? Just missing the command/ symbol to signal to Pinescript that its a new line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQNeJ.png)[This is what I get when I just paste the command into Pinescript, it sees it as different entry lines, which is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f42d9.png)

So I tried to get the alert message into my pinescript and tried to have Pinescript read it as different lines but i cant seem to make it work.

So to repeat, I need the alert to be in different lines using Pinescript

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need different lines on your alert as the API wait for a json message.
But on the pinescript part, you should write your message this way (with single quote) :

```
alert_message = '{ "bot_id": "3114", "action": "open-position", "base_asset": " ", "quote_asset": " ", "api_key": " " }'
```

NB : Do not copy paste this line as the ' may be changed to ` . Please type it.